# SQL - Read, add and update at once

Tags: sql, csv

I do have a csv file with id's and content to add to a table.

file:

***id;data***

***1;"D"***

Is there an easy way to update a column using select of the existing content and update it with added content only with SQL?

e.g.
Existing content:

> column = "A, B, C"

data to add for column (based on id) from csv file:  "D"

kind of: `UPDATE test SET column = "SELECT * FROM column WHERE id=..." + ",D" WHERE id=...`

result should be:

> column = "A, B, C, D"

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: You need to load your data into a staging table and then join it to the target table.

Comment: working with mysql in this case @Kazi

Comment: thx for the hint with staging table @Stu